# What are the ways to include new css file into magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

Please help me I have created new custom theme in magento 2 but I am facing problem to add new css file into theme.

For your information I have deploy code using composer to pub folder. Css files are copying there but not including those to frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you start [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html).

Add your CSS as part of a layout as discussed [in this topic](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html).

If you have other questions, please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

**Recently In magento2 I have included css file in catalog_product_view.xml as**

```
<head>
    <css src="mage/gallery/styles-view.css"/>
</head>
```